# Unit Testing magento config

Tags: unit-testing, magento, phpunit

When unit testing in magento, shoul I be using mocks for config tests?

I now there is the ecomdev module etc out there so please no answers directing me to this :)

I'm simply wondering whether any unit tests against the config for my modules should config object be mocked?

Comment: Possibly of value: [Alan Storm's Pulsestorm Chaos module](https://github.com/astorm/Pulsestorm/tree/master/app/code/community/Pulsestorm/Chaos)

Comment: Because in Magento 1 dependencies are spread everywhere in the code you can't really unit test it. However, you can write integration tests and change config, registry, etc. in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing in magento is hard. And to be honest not really possible at the moment (it will hopefully be completely different with magento 2). So if you ask me: No. don't test against mock objects, too much work, nearly no effect.

Test against the real config.

Comment: Can you eloborate a little on this? i.e. why is it difficult?  Im also struggling with deciding how to mock products and other models but it is difficult to me because of magic getters and setters. Do you have advice

Comment: great. When I wrote this, I didn't attend the TDD course by @IvanChepurnyi Sure you can test against mocks. Have a look on https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit and config fixtures. There is no need for a mock, just set the fixture